# Parsing string array into multi-dimensional array c#

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array, string-parsing

What is the best and easiest way to convert string array into array which each element in the array contains two dimensional array.

Example:

If my string looks like:

```
3 2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
```

First line:

```
3 2 3
```

means that I have 3 blocks of 2X3 and I would like to insert it into array (in size 3 in example above) which each element in the array contains two dimensional array (in size 2X3 in the example above) with the below content:

```
arr[0] = {{1,2,3), {4,5,6}}
arr[1] = {{7,8,9), {10,11,12}}
arr[2] = {{13,14,15), {16,17,18}}
```

Comment: Where are you having problems? Reading the string, splitting the string into integers, or getting the integers into your array structure?

Comment: @BJMyers splitting the corresponding strings into the arrays